# how to read data from an arraylist in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist

I have a JSON arraylist , Need to read data from it using php. I have tried it and failed simply. I will give all in the following

**Input data: JSON**

```
{    

    "orderHistory":[
        {
        "product_name": "mike",
        "product_price": 15000,
        "product_id": 5
        },
        {
        "product_name": "tv",
        "product_price": 25000,
        "product_id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

**PHPcode**

```
// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        extract($row);
echo '{';
        echo '"message": "array added."';

    echo '}';

}
```

Error :

`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::fetch() in`

Comment: `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` is used along with database queries. It's not applicable to an already decoded array.

Comment: So could you please tell me the php code to read the data

Answer (score 0):

your error is about the undefined method
there is no function with name fetch in your class $data
recheck your $data class

---

please check below codes.
i use your json and access to all data
you can act with your data as array like this

```
$str = '{"orderHistory":[{"product_name": "mike","product_price": 15000,"product_id": 5},{"product_name": "tv","product_price": 25000,"product_id": 3}]}';
$a = json_decode($str);
echo (json_encode($a->orderHistory));
echo ($a->orderHistory[0]->product_name);
echo ($a->orderHistory[1]->product_name);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me How to read data (json arraylist )using php and store that in a varibale

Comment: check my answer again dude